# Get source from image from webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I want to get the image source from this website:
https://www.pixiv.net/en/artworks/77619496

But every time I try to scrape it with bs4 I keep failing, I've tried other posts too but couldn't get it to work.
It keeps returning None

```
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.pixiv.net/en/artworks/77564597'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
x = soup.find("img")
print(x)
```

Comment: check my answer below, you can increase sleep time to give the page time to loads.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at *chrome debug console*'s network section or the console in the browser you are browsing in, you should see that there is no `img` elements at the beginning, the page generates `img` elements by executing javascript. However, I inspected the page and there is a `meta` element which has image data in it and you can parse it with JSON as shown:

```py
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.pixiv.net/en/artworks/77564597'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
x = soup.find("meta", {"id": "meta-preload-data"}).get("content")

usefulData = json.loads(x)

print(usefulData)
```

The sample output is [here](https://hastebin.com/ositapuzix.json).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but whenever I try accesing one of the links in the url section it says 403 forbidden, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I tried and I am not sure why that happens, it happened to me too. Probably something to do with cookies but don't know.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


browser = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'https://www.pixiv.net/en/artworks/77564597'
sada = browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
source = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'sc-fzXfPI fRnFme'}):
    for img in item.findAll('img', attrs={'class': 'sc-fzXfPJ lclRkv'}):
        print(img.get('src'))
```

Output:

```
https://i.pximg.net/c/250x250_80_a2/custom-thumb/img/2019/11/28/00/02/59/78026183_p0_custom1200.jpg
https://i.pximg.net/c/250x250_80_a2/img-master/img/2019/10/31/04/15/04/77564597_p0_square1200.jpg
https://i.pximg.net/c/250x250_80_a2/img-master/img/2019/08/30/07/23/45/76528190_p0_square1200.jpg
https://i.pximg.net/c/250x250_80_a2/img-master/img/2019/08/23/08/01/08/76410568_p0_square1200.jpg
https://i.pximg.net/c/250x250_80_a2/img-master/img/2019/07/24/03/41/47/75881545_p0_square1200.jpg
https://i.pximg.net/c/250x250_80_a2/img-master/img/2019/05/30/04/24/27/74969583_p0_square1200.jpg
https://i.pximg.net/c/250x250_80_a2/custom-thumb/img/2019/11/28/00/02/59/78026183_p0_custom1200.jpg
https://i.pximg.net/c/250x250_80_a2/img-master/img/2019/10/31/04/15/04/77564597_p0_square1200.jpg
https://i.pximg.net/c/250x250_80_a2/img-master/img/2019/08/30/07/23/45/76528190_p0_square1200.jpg
```